# Displaying download Progress in iOS status bar

Tags: ios, uiprogressview

I would like to display the download progress in the iOS status bar the same way android does. I know we can show the activity indicator but I was thinking

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot display download progress in the iOS status bar. The iOS Human Interface Guidelines for Progress Indicators shows some alternatives: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/controls/progress-indicators/

A brief summary of the options:

1. Display a spinner using a `UIActivityIndicatorView`.
2. Display a progress bar with `UIProgressView`.
3. Show the network activity indicator in the status bar.

You can also roll your own implementations of the spinner or progress bar, or use one of many third-party frameworks.

Hope that helps!